# Is rsync capable of taking account of moved files to update their location when making a synchronization?

Tags: rsync, backup

I am wondering if sync can up to date the location of moved file, using some id or tracking data that would allow to identify specific file relocation?

thanks for any hint.

Comment: I would test an asumption: it just detects the absence of the moved file and update the interested directory accordingly

Comment: If the file is moved within the same directory, then option `--fuzzy` can help.

Comment: git tracks files within a repository by their hash which allows moved files to be identified.

Answer (score 2):

No, rsync does not detect that a file has moved, only that a file has been deleted and another has been created.

As @wurtel has already said, the `--fuzzy` option might help optimize the data copy (not just for moved files, but also when there are any files with similar content around).

If you want the old file instance to be removed then you will need one of the `--delete` options.